# Error while AWS login through google in react native

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, google-signin

I'm working on AWS login through google I'm getting loggedin i have print the alert. but the problem i'm getting into catch error after login.I have print the alert i'm getting 13 alert after login as shown in code. Alert.alert("13");
There is App.js class in which google button is append with login google. i'm writing the code for auth class in which the procedure is going on between the AWS login through google. I have followed this link in github.
https://github.com/patw0929/react-native-amplify-cognito-example

```js
export const loginGoogle = () => {
  return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
    const user = await GoogleSignin.signIn().catch(error => {
      // console.log('WRONG SIGNIN', error);
      console.log('getOpenIdToken', getOpenIdToken);
      Alert.alert("13");
    });
    if (user) {
      const credential = await googleGetCredential();
      if (credential) {
        const result = await getOpenIdToken('accounts.google.com',
          credential.identityId, credential.idToken);
        resolve(result);
        Alert.alert("8");
        return;
      }
      reject('Authentication failed');
      console.log('failed');
      Alert.alert("9");
      return;
    }
    return;
  });
};

export const getOpenIdToken = async(provider, identityId, token) => {
  const payload = {
    IdentityId: identityId,
    Logins: {
      [provider]: token,
    },
  };
  Alert.alert("10");
  try {
    const rsp = await fetch(COGNITO_IDENTITY_API, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers({
        'X-Amz-Target': 'AWSCognitoIdentityService.GetOpenIdToken',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1',
        random: new Date().valueOf(),
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify(payload),
    });
    if (!rsp.ok) {
      logout();
    } else {
      const json = await rsp.json();
      return json.Token;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error of getOpenIdToken: ', e);
  }
};

const googleConfigure = () => {
  GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices({
      autoResolve: true
    })
    .then(() =>
      GoogleSignin.configure({
        iosClientId: GOOGLE_SIGNIN_IOS_CLIENT_ID,
        webClientId: GOOGLE_SIGNIN_WEBCLIENT_ID,
      })
    );
};

export const init = () => {
  googleConfigure();
};
```

I want to gettoken to print  in the alert.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDi5Q.png)Bram, In this question a lot of information, is missing. Atleast, error message needs to be there

1. First of all, the library which you are using is old and try using AWS Amplify instead, which is far superior in features and it been tested for security and errors.
2. In AWS Federated Login can be done in 2 ways, one using Cognito User Pool as well as using Cognito Identity Pool. I hope you are using Cognito Identity Pool.
3. Please add the Google Client ID in Edit identity pool->Authentication providers->Google+
4. Whitelist the domain which you are hitting in Google Developer account.

Full documention is here
https://itnext.io/google-sign-in-using-aws-amplify-and-amazon-cognito-69cc3bf219ad

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/amplify-framework-adds-authentication-features-and-enhancements-for-ios-and-android-mobile-sdks/

Comment: which information you want. i have added client id and secret id in AWS. I'm not getting token in return could please help me in this.

Comment: I'm getting {"name".GooglesigninError","code":10}. this is the error which i have shown in alert.

Comment: can you please help me i'm stuck in very bad issue

Comment: I'm gettiing error {"name":"GoogleSigninError","code":10}

Comment: I have added image of the code also where i'm getting error

Comment: Kindly confirm whether these instructions were completed. https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/cognito-hosted-ui-federated-identity#google-sign-in-instructions

Comment: Yes, i have followed these instructions.